# CSS - Fixed header and message

Tags: css

I have a basic layout with a fixed header like this...

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("message");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#message {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

header {
  background:teal;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}

.content {
background:wheat;
padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="message">
    This is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed length
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Close Message</button>
</div>
<header>
    This is my header
</header>
<div class="content">
  <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
</div>
```

I want the header to be fixed as well as the message, but when I set it to fixed it breaks the layout. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks the layout"? Do you mean that "content" is hidden behind the header and message? If so - you need to style "content" element either by adding `padding` or `margin` to it and make the value of padding/margin equal or higher than the sum of height of the header and message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with not supporting IE < 11 (https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) use flexbox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("message");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#message {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="message">
        This is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed length
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Close Message</button>
    </div>

    <header>
        This is my header
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
      </p>
      <p>
          Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
      </p>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
      </p>
      <p>
          Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
      </p>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
      </p>
      <p>
          Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
      </p>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
      </p>
      <p>
          Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
      </p>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
      </p>
      <p>
          Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another container that you make `fixed` and the header will be on the good place after removing the message. You may also adjust the padding using JS:

```js
document.querySelector('.content').style.paddingTop=document.querySelector('.fixed').clientHeight+"px";
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("message");
    x.style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector('.content').style.paddingTop="50px";
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.fixed {
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
}
#message {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

header {
  background:teal;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}

.content {
background:wheat;
padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
<div id="message">
    This is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed length
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Close Message</button>
</div>
<header>
    This is my header
</header>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please not that when the message is open part of the content is hidden. Judging by `padding-top: 50px` in the original code it's not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. All you need to do is to remove `position:fixed;` from `header` class to have it fixed. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/krc6xaLz/1/)

```
.header {
  background:teal;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Please include any relevant code in your answer. Use the "Copy snippet to answer" button on the OP's code snippet to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see what the problem is. If you want the message to overlap, use this code:

```
#message {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add fixed position to a tag element on html it make the element stay on the screen ignoring the parent element. So if you put position: fixed to an element and top: 0 it says that the element should stay always on view at the top of the screen.

So if it is the behave you are expecting to is that the message and header should scroll and stays always on view then you should also add the position: fixed to your message: element.

```
#message {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

If you want the header to stay put where it is without scrolling along with the screen you should remove the position: fixed from header.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some javascript because `fixed` elements are taken out of the position layout, so there's no way to have the browser calculate the top offset of the `header` with just css.

Here's one solution, which runs a function `onload` to measure the calculated offset, set the `top` of the `header`, then set the `message` to `position:fixed`.

It works, but note that if the user changes the size of the browser window, the `top` property won't be updated and you'll have unexpected results. You'll have to handle that yourself if you like this beginning ;).

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("message");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
  var headerTop = header.offsetTop;
  header.style.top = `${headerTop}px`;
  document.getElementById("message").style.position = "fixed";
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#message {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

header {
  background:teal;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}

.content {
background:wheat;
padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="message">
    This is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed lengthThis is a message, the text can be dynamic so no fixed length
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Close Message</button>
</div>
<header>
    This is my header
</header>
<div class="content">
  <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce interdum nibh non convallis fringilla. Vivamus consequat pellentesque tortor eget dictum. Pellentesque fermentum nisi arcu, nec rutrum diam consectetur ut. Vestibulum ex risus, feugiat eu commodo in, dapibus vel velit. Nam eget lacus tortor. Mauris in risus diam. Sed magna velit, blandit ac pulvinar malesuada, malesuada vel ipsum. Nam imperdiet lobortis velit sed aliquet. Vivamus facilisis ante orci, ut convallis lacus sagittis eu. Maecenas ornare nisi a est semper imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque rutrum condimentum tincidunt. Nunc ut mattis diam, sed aliquam nisl. Aenean ullamcorper tellus et pretium molestie. Maecenas id tristique quam. Vestibulum non est enim.
  </p>
  <p>
      Aliquam sem ligula, facilisis non justo tempus, posuere tincidunt metus. Aliquam vestibulum nisl vel porta sagittis. Sed tempus vulputate metus, non dictum eros vulputate in. Vestibulum in dolor id metus facilisis porttitor. In sit amet mi molestie, auctor tortor vel, lobortis tortor. Ut bibendum mi dolor, vitae mollis nibh commodo eget. Donec sit amet dolor ex. Curabitur porta, ex id fermentum commodo, massa nulla blandit nunc, vitae suscipit orci nulla eget augue. In egestas feugiat nisl, et interdum orci feugiat eget. Vivamus egestas urna non vulputate finibus. Ut efficitur eros in dictum tempus. Integer ultricies consectetur risus sit amet venenatis. Duis et gravida justo, et pulvinar dolor. Proin sed imperdiet lectus. Sed quis ultricies orci, sit amet vehicula diam.
  </p>
</div>
```